# Can't bundle pod into cocoa touch framework

Tags: ios, cocoa, frameworks, touch, cocoapods

I want to create a networking framework for a project I'm working on. This networking framework will be distributed as a private pod.

I've created my (let's call it) SDK project, and I've also created a sample app project. Both folders are on the disk in the same folder, next to each other

In my SDK folder I have a Podfile
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
    # platform :ios, '9.0'

```
target 'mySDK' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire'

  target 'mySDKTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

I ran `pod install` and after the workspace has been generated, I've dragged and dropped my SampleApp project also in the workspace.

So current on my disk I have

```
parent folder
 |
 |- SDK Folder
 |- SampleApp Folder
```

And my Workspace looks like this 
[image: Workspace]

So at this point, I want to run the sample app with the attached SDK (sample app doesn't do anything), so I link the SDK
[image: Linkage]

But when I run it, the app crashes

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mySDK-gvlfyunirdzboifhygkmmcjnllzv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mySDK.framework/mySDK
```

Reason: image not found

But the SDK if I `cmd+B` build it, it builds successfully.

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid, but can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just follow the cocoapods guide on setting up a private pod?
It will create the entire structure for you, including a build in sample project.

[Create Cocoapod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html)

[Create private repo](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html)

If you're looking for a step by step instruction blog, there are plenty available as well. [Here's a decent one](https://medium.com/@shahabejaz/create-and-distribute-private-libraries-with-cocoapods-5b6507b57a03)

Comment: Ok, so I will redo everything from start based on this awesome tutorial, but I what I don't understand, is how I can bundle Alamofire as a dependency for my pod than.

Comment: in your private pod, you'll add alamofire as a dependency in the .podspec file


s.dependency 'Alamofire'

Comment: Edit: oh, so I add it as a dependency! Thank you!

Comment: The nice thing with cocoapods is that you're able to add dependencies, and even other private dependencies that you might build out in the future. (just dont forget to add source to the private repo if you need to add private pods as dependencies